# Hibernate tool to use synonym in database

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-tools

Does hibernate tool have the ability to connect to synonym tables in the database? I was asked about this by my the DBA this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, just enable the property 'hibernate.synonyms' in your persistence.xml

```
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.synonyms" value="true"/>

    </properties>
```

And annotate your entity class with

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "<repalce with synonym name>")
```

Comment: Since the db is using synonyms is there something we can do to get the tables to be displayed in the configuration section of the hibernate tool?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, just avoid mentioning the schema in the cfg file.. my file ..

```
  <session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:60003/IHR1D</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property><property name="hibernate.default_catalog"/></session-factory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view from synonym table;

```
CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW AS ( SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE@SYNONYM)
```

Then you can create entity with that VIEW name:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_VIEW")
```